# MemoryError using Python and Doc2Vec

Tags: python, machine-learning, doc2vec

I'm trying to train a Doc2vec for massive data. I have a **20k** files with **72GB** in total, and write this code:

```
def train():
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
    data = []
    random.shuffle(onlyfiles)
    tagged_data = []
    t = 0
    try:
        for file_name in onlyfiles:
            with open(mypath+"/"+file_name, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
                txt = file.read()
                tagged_data.append([word_tokenize(txt.lower()), [str(t)]])
                t+=1
    except Exception as e:
        print(t)
        return 
    print("Files Loaded")
    max_epochs = 1000
    vec_size = 500
    alpha = 0.025

    model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=vec_size,
                    alpha=alpha, workers=1,
                    min_alpha=0.00025,
                    min_count=1,
                    dm=1)

    print("Model Works")
    print("Building vocabulary")

    model.build_vocab(tagged_data)
    print("Trainning")
    for epoch in range(max_epochs):
        print("Iteration {0}".format(epoch))
        model.train(tagged_data,
                    total_examples=model.corpus_count,
                    epochs=model.iter)
        model.alpha -= 0.0002
        model.min_alpha = model.alpha

    model.save(model_name)
    print("Model Saved")
```

But when I run this method, this error appears:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "doc2vec.py", line 20, in train
    tagged_data.append([word_tokenize(txt.lower()), [str(t)]])
MemoryError
```

And only **3k** files are treated. But when view memory, the `python` process show that only **1.7%** from memory was used.
Is there any parameter I can inform to `python` to solve?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error long before even trying `Doc2Vec`, so this isn't really a `Doc2Vec` question - it's a problem with your Python data handling. Do you have enough RAM to load 72GB of disk-data (which might expand a bit when represented in Python string objects) into RAM?

But also, you won't usually have to bring an entire corpus into memory, by appending to a giant list, to do any of these tasks. Read things one at a time, and process from an iterable/iterator, perhaps writing interim results (like tokenized text) back to the IO sources. This article may be helpful:

https://rare-technologies.com/data-streaming-in-python-generators-iterators-iterables/

Finally, if your code *did* proceed to the `Doc2Vec` section, you'd have other problems. Whatever online example you're consulting as a model has many bad practices. For example:

- a typical interation-count is 10-20; you certainly wouldn't use 1000 for a 72GB dataset
- `min_count=1` leads to a much bigger model; usually discarding low-frequency words is necessary and may even improve resulting vector quality, and larger datasets (and 72GB is very very big) tend to user larger rather than minimal `min_count` settings
- most people shouldn't be using non-default `alpha`/`min_alpha` values, or trying to manage them with their own calculations, or even calling `train()` more than once. `train()` has its own `epochs` parameter which if used will smoothly handle the learning-rate `alpha` for you. As far as I can tell, 100% of the people who call `train()` multiple times in their own loop are doing it wrong, and I have no idea where they keep getting these examples.
- Training goes much slower with `workers=1`; especially with a large dataset you'll want to try larger `workers` values, and the optimal value for training throughput in gensim versions up through 3.5.0 is usually somewhere in the range from 3-12 (assuming you have at least that many CPU cores).

So your current code would probably result in a model larger than RAM, training single-thread slowly and 1000s of times more than necessary, with much of the training happening with a nonsensical negative-alpha which makes the model worse every cycle. If it miraculously didn't `MemoryError` during model initialization, it'd run for months or years and end up with nonsense results.